# Node express route: static path error

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I'm writing my first serious MEAN application and have a problem with my routing. The basic setup works, I have a bunch of GET and POST routes that work perfectly. I ran into this problem trying to serve a static html file `somepage.html`for the route `GET /somepage/:uuid`.

In **app.js**:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
var routes = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', routes);
```

In **routes/index.js**:

```
router.get('/somepage/:uuid', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile('public/somepage.html', {root: __dirname + "/.."});
});
```

What happens is that that the html file is loaded, but all loading of static resources take the wrong path. I expect it to load script.js from `public/script.js` but it tries to fetch it at `somepage/script.js`

What did I miss?

P.S. What I'm really trying to achieve is to pass that `uuid` between pages. At page one, an angular controller has the `uuid` and the controller at somepage.html should also be aware of it. Is there a better way than passing it in the url? The server doesn't need to know the uuid.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet from `somepage.html` ? You probably need to do `<script src="/script.js">` (absolute path) to properly match your static middleware.

Comment: That solved it, thanks!

Comment: Hi @emolaus please can you share your solution ?